# Why is my owl carousel slider showing only 3 items in a row when there are supposed to be 4?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I've set up my owl carousel slider to display 4 items in a row, but right now it's only displaying 3 at a time. It used to show up 4 items when I first used it, but I'm not sure what changed that it's now displaying 3, even when I specified it to be 4.

```
  <div id="offer-slider" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/016.png" alt="door">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">Wooden door</h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">200</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>250</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/010.png" alt="concrete-mixer">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">Concrete Mixers</h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">430</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>500</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/011.png" alt="brick-making-machine">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">Brick Making Machines
                    </h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">1200</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>1500</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/018.png" alt="upvc-windows">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">UPVC Windows</h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">600</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>700</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/016.png" alt="door">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">Wooden door</h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">200</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>250</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/010.png" alt="concrete-mixer">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">Concrete Mixers</h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">430</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>500</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/011.png" alt="brick-making-machine">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">Brick Making Machines
                    </h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">1200</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>1500</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="offer-container card">
                    <div class="offer-image">
                        <img src="./images/018.png" alt="upvc-windows">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="offer-title">UPVC Windows</h3>
                    <div class="order-offer">
                        <span class="current-price">600</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                        <del class="discount-price">
                        <span>700</span><span class="currency">AED</span>
                    </del>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-offer">Request</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is my js code where I set it up to be 4 items :

```
var offerSlider = $('#offer-slider');

offerSlider.owlCarousel({
    **items: 4,**
    autoWidth: true,
    itemsDesktop: [1200, 4],
    itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 4],
    itemsMobile: [600, 1],
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: ["", ""],
    pagination: true,
    autoPlay: true,

});

$('.best-offers-left-button').click(function() {
    offerSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');

});

$('.best-offers-right-button').click(function() {
    offerSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
```

Comment: it's working well

Comment: Is it showing 4 items for you?

Comment: yeah, what version of owl are you using ?

Comment: The latest one , which is 2.3.4. Do you have a large screen ?

Comment: if you're using the latest ver so use the samples from the sample folder

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code -
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#offer-slider").owlCarousel({
items : 3,
loop:true,
dots:true,
autoplay:true,
pagination:false,
navigation:false,
responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
0:{
items:1,
nav:false
},
600:{
items:2,
nav:false
},
1000:{
items:3,
nav:false,
loop:false
}
}
});
});

Comment: Thank you. However, I am trying to display 4, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to write your responsive code like this

`$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ loop:true, margin:10, responsiveClass:true, responsive:{ 0:{ items:1, }, 600:{ items:3 }, 1000:{ items:5, } } })`